# How to debug a 'can't set attribute' error

Tags: python, oop

An order object have different task objects, within each task I need to keep track of the order also. Indeed, I will define different orders later.
I defined the following classes.

How to fix this?

Comment: You haven't defined a *setter* for your property - https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property

Answer (score 2):

You have a property and class attribute with the same name in the `Task` class. Since you haven't defined a setter for the `command` property, you get this error.

To fix this, you should probably make the `Task` class store the command in an attribute with a different name and add a setter, perhaps something along the lines of:

```py
class Task:
    def __init__(self, ..., command):
        # some init stuff ...
        self._command = command

    @property
    def command(self):
        # sanity check here...
        return self._command

    @command.setter
    def command(self, x):
        self._command = x
```

Or if you don't want the command property changed after the task is created, just leave out the setter.

Comment: If I now longer need to know what are the tasks that belongs to the same command what is better to do ? 1. Remove the tasks attribute from the Command and keep Task as it is. 2. Make the Job inherits the methods of the Command and remove the attribute command from Task?